# Increment number in php every time data is received from sql

Tags: php, sql, ajax

I am trying to make a program that can get data from Sql using php. the received data is a number from 1 to 5 and each number presents a color. every time a number is received a counter adds 1 for that color in html. I have been able to code this but if the page is refreshed the counted value becomes 0.

```
<?php

while( $row = sqlsrv_fetch_array( $stmt, SQLSRV_FETCH_ASSOC)) {
    echo $row['name'].", ".$row['color']";

 $red = "5";
 $pink = "4";
 $yellow = "3";
 $black = "2";
 $white = "1";



 $colorid = $row['color']; 

 if ($colorid == $red){
     echo "Red";
     $re = 1;
     $re = ++;
  
 } elseif ($colorid == $pink){
     echo "Pink";
     $pi = 1;
     $pi = ++;
  
 } elseif ($colorid == $yellow){
     echo "Yellow";
     $ye = 1;
     $ye = ++$;
  
 } elseif ($colorid == $black){
     echo "Black";
     $blk = 1;
     $blk = ++;
  
 } elseif ($colorid == $white){
     echo "White";
     $wh = 1;
     $wh = ++;
  
 } else {
     echo "Cannot verify the color code";
 }
}

?>

    <div>
        <span>White:     </span><input name="white" value="<?php echo (isset($wh))?$wh:'';?>">
    
        <span>Black:     </span><input name="black" value="<?php echo (isset($blk))?$blk:'';?>">
    
        <span>Yellow:     </span><input name="yellow" value="<?php echo (isset($ye))?$ye:'';?>">
    
        <span>Pink:     </span><input name="pink" value="<?php echo (isset($pi))?$pi:'';?>">
    
        <span>Red :     </span><input name="red" value="<?php echo (isset($re))?$re:'';?>">

    </div>
```

Comment: why is this tagged `javascript`?

Comment: Just a side note, it's a bad practice to use if-else-if statements for simple equality checks for your `$colorid`. You should use a switch statement for that

Comment: use Sessions to keep values after refreshing the page.

Comment: @Professor Abronsius can you please check my code and let me know if you have any solutions.